# Why wasn't this question deleted automatically?

Tags: support, bug, specific-question

Here's the link: https://superuser.com/questions/614234/errorunable-to-acsess-jarfile

As it's downvoted and old, it is supposed to be [deleted automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006), but that doesn't happen.

Looks like that's because it's locked ("*comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews*").

I suppose, the strange notice "*migration rejected from stackoverflow.com*" has something to do with this.

Is this a migration bug?
Or does it all work as it should?

Comment: This [google search](https://www.google.se/search?q=site:superuser.com+"migration+rejected") shows that there are more questions like this and I think many (most?)of them should be deleted.